# Simultaneous equations $y^2=4ax , y+px=2ap+ap^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:**

> Using
>   $$y^2=4ax$$ $$y+px=2ap+ap^3$$
>
> Show that $$y=-2a\left( \frac{2+p^2}{p} \right)$$

**Working:**
$$Substitute \rightarrow x=\frac{y^2}{4a}$$
$$\begin{align} 
y+p\left(\frac{y^2}{4a}\right)&=2ap+ap^3\\
4ay+py^2&=8a^2p +4a^2p^3\\
y(4a+py)&=8a^2p +4a^2p^3\\
0&=py^2 + 4ay −8a^2p − 4a^2 p^3 \\
\end{align}$$

And I am stuck there. Any suggestions on how to move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$0=py^2 + 4ay −8a^2p − 4a^2 p^3= (2ap^2+4a+py)(2ap-y)$$

Well the basic approach is to use the quadratic formaula: treat the above as a quadratic in $y$. so 
$$\begin{align*}
 y  &=  \frac{-4a \pm \sqrt {16a^2 + 4p(8a^2+4a^2p^4)}}{2p}\\
&  =\ldots
\end{align*}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I know how to solve from here, the thing is I can't reach this point without looking at the answer. Mind sharing your method on how you found this?

Comment: @Panayiotis: I added to my post. see if you okay. if not let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve for `y`, aren't you? Look at the last equation you wrote and think of it as an equation where `y` is the variable. Does anything suggest itself in terms of solving for `y`?

Comment: Okay I know that is a quadratic, but I have no idea how to factorize it